# Why is Openshift Online Starter refusing to activate a pod for over two weeks?

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

I have been using Openshift Online Starter for some time for a small project.  However, for the last two weeks, the pods for my system (which was working fine earlier) have simply refused to start.  The program builds ok, deploys ok, and then the final pod gets stuck in "Pending."  In the "Events" tab in the console, this error or a slight variation is always repeated:

`0/106 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had disk pressure, 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate, 11 node(s) were unschedulable, 37 node(s) exceed max volume count, 50 Insufficient cpu, 6 node(s) didn't match node selector.`

I know that since August 6th the [Openshift status website](https://status.starter.openshift.com/) has reported an "elevated level of API errors" and also logging errors on my particular server (us-west-2).  However, does this mean Openshift Starter is effectively unusable until this problem is fixed?  Or is the problem somewhere in my program?

**NB:** I'm also aware that Openshift Starter is not intended for production projects.  I'm just asking whether this is an outage in Openshift Online or not.

Comment: You can report issues at https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html

Comment: I did so just now, but I thought that Stack Overflow is the usual place they ask you to post questions about Openshift Starter...

Comment: This is related to capacity issues in the cluster, nothing that your application is doing wrong. Because the cluster is so popular, we're having to increase our capacity to fully handle it. Please be patient while we resolve this.

Comment: StackOverflow is okay for asking questions about using OpenShift, but for what would look like an operational issue, better to use the contact form, as operations team may not always know there is an issue unless someone reports it. The main people who monitor StackOverflow for OpenShift questions aren't always connected with operations.

Comment: @Will Gordon thank you. I just received a response from the contact form saying the same.  I am leaving this question here in case anyone else has similar problems, and am answering it below saying the same.

Answer (score 0):

Both Will Gordon in the comments above and the reply I received from the contact form say that this is a problem in the Openshift cluster, not in my app, so if you are experiencing similar problems this is probably true for you too.